# strange behaviour when cropping a numpy/opencv image

Tags: python, arrays, image, opencv, numpy

I'm really puzzled by the way of indexing a numpy multidimensional array. My goal is to crop a region from an image I loaded using opencv.
Loading the image works great:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = cv2.imread(start_filename)
print img.shape
```

shape is displayed as

```
(2000L, 4096L, 3L)
```

Now I want to cut a part from the image which ranges from pixels 550 to 1550 in the first dimension and only consists of the last 782 pixels of the second dimension. I tried

```
img=img[550:1550][:-782][:]
print img.shape
```

Now the shape is displayed as

```
(782L, 4096L, 3L)
```

I'm confused, whats the correct way of indexing for the crop operation?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of cropping image is using slicing technique:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("lenna.png")
crop_img = img[200:400, 100:300] # Crop from x, y, w, h -> 100, 200, 300, 400
# NOTE: its img[y: y + h, x: x + w] and *not* img[x: x + w, y: y + h]
```

In your case, the final cropped image may be reproduced as:

```
crop_img=img[550:1550, -782:]
print crop_img.shape
```

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in other answers you could use `img[550:1550,-782:,:]` but this will give you only a ***read only*** view of the array. It means that you cannot modify it. If you want to modify the image after you crop it you could use the [ix_](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html#numpy.ix_) function of Numpy for indexing.

```
img=img[ix_(range(550, 1550), range(img.shape[1]-782, img.shape[1]))]
# or
img=img[ix_(range(550, 1550), range(img.shape[1]-782, img.shape[1]), range(3))]
```

After this your shape will look like:

```
(1000, 782, 3)
```